# How to get variable from JavaScript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

i need to  transfer a variable from js to a php page then insert it in the database

the Js code

```
    function tableText(tableCell) {
    var x =tableCell.innerHTML;
     console.log(x);
}
```

also tried the ajax

```
function tableText(tableCell) {
    var x =tableCell.innerHTML;
    console.log(x);
    $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'try.php', 
    data: x ,
    complete: function(text){
         return text; }
 });
}
```

not sure if i got it right and i don't know how to call it in the php page

so How to get variable from JavaScript to PHP  ??

Comment: read more about jquery's ajax function - the data you send should be an object, not a simple value

Comment: You probably want to send the entire html table and save it in a database table, you can learn these basic (insert/select/update/delete) or CRUD operations easily . Juste get your self a cup of coffee , a good  YouTube tutorial , couple hours of free time and some enthusiasm towards programming.

Comment: ohh no no no i know how to (insert/select/update/delete) prefectly i just need to transfer one Js variable to another php page ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: **(Edit, explanation set json)**

```js
function tableText(tableCell) {
    var x =tableCell.innerHTML;
    console.log(x);
    $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'try.php', 
    dataType: "json",
        data: { x:x },
    complete: function(text){
         return text; }
 });
}

function tableText(tableCell) {
    var x =tableCell.innerHTML;
    console.log(x);
    $.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'try.php', 
    dataType: "json",
        data: { x:x },
    success : function(text){
            $('#MyDiv').html(text);
        }
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*You can retrieve by `$_POST['x']` just like a normal post.*

For the **return** in php you need to use **`echo json_encode(['text'=>'ok']);`**.

Comment: @Kid thank you i thinkmit worked but how do i echo the variable in question the x ? sorry i'm just starting php and js

Comment: Please explain your code, it isn't useful when you just post `Try this: [code]`

Comment: @OumniaRanaSEGUENI you can find it in the $_POST variable in PHP. It would be $_POST['x'] I believe.

Comment: way too better answer than the other, HOWEVER jQuery is not necessary needed, you can use ```XMLHttpRequest``` or ```Fetch API``` to do this even better than jQuery (avoiding callback hell)

Comment: as @ethry explained correctly, ```echo $_POST['x'];``` will absolutely work, but try saving it in a local variable instead of the SUPER GLOBAL ```$_POST``` and before using it's value I suggest you to see if it has been posted correctly to your page using ```if ( isset( $_POST['x] ) ) { /* Your Other Codes Based On x*/}``` ,, and you can mark the answer as accepted if it worked and solved your problem

Comment: thank you @Kid and @MahdiarMransouri i don't know how to explain this it's working and also not working... once i wrote ``` echo $_POST['x']; ``` the x accually showed but only in network page ( right click inspect then network ) there the variable is showing but on the try.php it's not there !! the same for ``` if ( isset( $_POST['x] ) ) {}``` nothing is there

Comment: @OumniaRanaSEGUENI the try.php is getting executed(post) outside what you see on your page. To get response on your page u need to use a success handeling. A simple echo won't do it. I will update my answer with a lose extra snippet for now, it's late I need to quit.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending your data correctly with ajax, your ajax should look like this

Edit: Add a sweet alert to display a nice looking message after your insert

```
function tableText(tableCell) {
    var x =tableCell.innerHTML;
    console.log(x);
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'try.php', 
        data: {
            x:x
        },
        success: function(text) {
            //SWAL
            Swal.fire(
                'Success!!',
                text,
                'success'
            )
        }
     });
 }


<!-- SWEET ALERT -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

and on your try.php file

```
<?php
$_REQUEST['x'];//here you receive what you send thru ajax

//here goes your insert

echo json_encode('insert was successfull')//this msg is what you will see when you return text
?>
```